# How to create a Settings Panel with RadioGroup and save changes

Tags: android, radio-button, settings, background-color, radio-group

in my Android app there are two Activity (Main and Settings) with main.xml and settings.xml. I want to create a RadioGroup in Settings that works like a settings panel for users so they can select Backgroundcolor of Buttons. I'm trying to use onClick with each RadioButton and it work well but if I come back to main.xml che color is not saved. How can I create a settings panel for set BackgroundColor of Buttons in other activity and save it (or with a Save Button for users)?

Here, Settings' code:

```
public class Settings extends Main implements OnCheckedChangeListener {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.settings);
final Button back;
back= (Button) findViewById(R.id.back);

RadioButton redbtn, blubtn, grebtn;
redbtn= (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.redbtn);
blubtn= (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.blubtn);
grebtn= (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.grebtn);

redbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        back.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
        add.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
    }
});
back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        finish();
    }
});
}

@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup arg0, int arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}   
}
```

settings.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/title_settings"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:text="@string/settings"
    android:textSize="40sp" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/ButtonSettingsView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/title_settings"
    android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
    android:text="@string/BtnSet"
    android:textSize="30sp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/back"
    android:layout_width="70sp"
    android:layout_height="70sp"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/title_settings"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/title_settings"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/ButtonSettingsView"
    android:text="Back"/>

<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/ButtonSettings"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/ButtonSettingsView"
    android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/redbtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/red"/>
    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/blubtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/blue"  />
    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/grebtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/grey"/>
</RadioGroup>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course it won't save it for other `Activities` because when you start another then that `Activity` will use whatever its default is in xml. You need to save the color somehow then reference it in your other `Activities`. One way to do this, if you want it to persist when the user leaves and reenters the app, is to use [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref). Then you can open up these prefs in your other `Activites`, value saved, and change background accordingly.

If you only want it to change the color for the time that the user is currently in the app then you could create a `static` class to store this variable and change the colors according to that value.